# How to get the whole row of a JTable to save it into another table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, tablemodel

I am trying to validate that when the column step is equal to 2 the row is copied to another `JTable`.

But the `jtable_step2` I have not initialized correctly,
that's why it returns the error:

```
jtable_step2.setValueAt(jtable.getValueAt(i, j), row, j);

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
```

How do I copy the same columns and rows that satisfy the condition?

Java code:

```
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class TestJTableCopy {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String data[][]={ {"1","/LOCAL/USER/LOCAL", "20220421", "1"},
                          {"1","/LOACL/USER/LOCAL", "20220421", "2"},
                          {"1","/LOACL/USER/LOCAL", "20220422", "2"} };
        String columns[] = {"LINE", "SOURCE", "DATE", "STEP"};
        final JTable jtable = new JTable(data,columns);
        
        JTable jtable_step2 = new JTable();
        //jtable2.addColumn(columns);
        int row = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < jtable.getRowCount(); i++) {
            //STEP == 2
            if (jtable.getValueAt(i, 3).equals("2")) {

                for(int j = 0; j < jtable.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    jtable_step2.setValueAt(jtable.getValueAt(i, j), row, j);
                }
                row++;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < jtable_step2.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < jtable_step2.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + jtable_step2.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jtable_step2.setValueAt(jtable.getValueAt(i, j), row, j);
```

You can't use the setValueAt(...) method because the row doesn't exist in the second table. You need to add a new row of data to the model of the table.

You do this by:

1. Creating a Vector, lets say "row"
2. Iterate through all the columns of the row you want to copy and add each item to the table
3. in the second table you use `jtable_step2.addRow( row )` to add a new row of data to the model of the table.